# JS: Cross Browser Compatibility - my JS works in chrome, not in FF

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox, jquery

I've got some JS which works in Chrome, but not in FireFox, and I'm too inexperienced in JS to be able to troubleshoot this without some assistance.

I tested it from `localhost` on my dev machine ***and*** from its deployed location (on our internal intranet) ... same results in both cases.

In chrome, it does exactly what I expect. It asynchronously catches a JSON object from the API and splashes it for the user.
In FF, it takes the user to the target API URL. No *"asynchronisity"*.

What tweaks can I do to support FF too??
(fortunately, FF & Chm are the only two I ***need*** to code against).

Any and all help will be greatly appreciated.

```
var submit_map_url = 'blahblah';  // dynamically generated by PHP
$('#mapper_form').submit(function() { 
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: submit_map_url, 
        data:$('#mapper_form').serialize(),
        success: function(response) {
            var response = $.parseJSON(response);


            if(response.status == 'failure'){
                alert(response.message); 
            }else{
                var doRedirect = true;

                $('#splash').fadeIn(800, function() {  // fade in
                    window.setTimeout ( function() {  // start a timer for auto redirect
                        $('#splash').fadeOut(1000, function() {  // fade out
                            if(doRedirect) window.location = redirect_target;  // then redirect
                        }) }
                    , 4000);  // 
                 });

                $('#splash').click(function(){  // on click
                    doRedirect = false;  // cancel the redirect request
                     $(this).fadeOut(700,function() {});  // and fade out
                 });

                 $('#countdown').countdown({until: +5, format: 'S'});

            }  // end IF/ELSE
        }  // end success:
    });  // ajax
    return false;
});
```

Comment: `$('#mapper_form').submit(function(event) { ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `event` parameter to you submit function. `$('#mapper_form').submit(function(event) {`

Chrome has a global event object `window.event` when you are in a event handler.